# how to reset edit path variable from text

Tags: windows-10

I apparently hit "Edit Text" in the Windows 10 "edit environment variable" screen for the Path variable.  Now it never comes up in the convenient format where each path component is separately editable.  Instead I have to edit in the old-fashioned way of a single text line.

Is there a way to reset the edit function to let me edit the path as separate components?

Comment: Maybe related: [Path enviroment variable editor BUG](https://superuser.com/questions/1234742/path-enviroment-variable-editor-bug)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the problem and the solution recommended there does work for me!

Answer (score 3):

As described in [path environment variable editor BUG](https://superuser.com/questions/1234742/path-enviroment-variable-editor-bug): the new path editor does not work if the first entry in the path starts with a %variable% reference that is not to a system-defined variable such as %SystemRoot%\system32. The fix is either to make the first entry in the path either NOT use an environment variable or use one of the system-defined variables.

Thanks to dxiv who commented on my question above.